# How to use cmakedefine preprocessor directive properly?

Tags: c++, cmake

Following [this instructions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/), I create a `headerconfig.h.in` file which contains `#cmakedefine USE_MYLIB`. On my `main.cpp` file i add `#include headerconfig.h.in`. And, I've set too the `CMakeLists.txt` file for this. But, I got this:

```
error: invalid preprocessing directive #cmakedefine
```

What did I do wrong? Is for some reason `cmake` can't reade `#cmakedefine` preprocessore?

Comment: I run into the same problem, and I did include my `headerconfig.h` in my `main.cpp` source code. However, I am also getting the error message from my IDE that the preprocessing directive of #cmakedefine is unrecognized. And of course my comipling failed. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should include not "headerconfig.h.in", but "headerconfig.h",
and add appropriate configure_file call in your cmake.
The idea is that cmake process headerconfig.h.in and generate headerconfig.h,
replace "#cmakedefine" with real values, and it uses headerconfig.h.in as template.